# /mingw32/libexec/git-core/git-sh-setup: 30: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")

Tags: windows, git, bash

I'm running git bash (2.7.4) on windows 7, and cannot use certain Git commands (rebase/stash) for example. throwing an error:

```
/mingw32/libexec/git-core/git-sh-setup: 30: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
```

Other basic commands like pull and push work okay.
Since upgrading from git 1.9 these commands fail.

**EDIT**

It may also be worth noting that git commands are working okay when running git through the windows command prompt, but not on BASH on windows

**EDIT 2**

Here is the function in the file (git-sh-setup) where i am erroring:

```
git_broken_path_fix () {
    case ":$PATH:" in
    *:$1:*) : ok ;;
    *)
        PATH=$(
            SANE_TOOL_PATH="$1"
            IFS=: path= sep=
            set x $PATH
            shift
            for elem
            do
                case "$SANE_TOOL_PATH:$elem" in
                (?*:/bin | ?*:/usr/bin) --------------This is line 30 that is erroring
                    path="$path$sep$SANE_TOOL_PATH"
                    sep=:
                    SANE_TOOL_PATH=
                esac
                path="$path$sep$elem"
                sep=:
            done
            echo "$path"
        )
        ;;
    esac
}
```

**EDIT 3**

I've solved my issue. it turns out (because of the fact that i'm runing git on windows, that my BASH path differs from my standar windows PATH)
The first location for by bin folder (containing files that git uses) was set to a default home directory on my machine that i no longer used. this directory has very old versions of files that were never updated along with bash or git.
This was spotted in a comparison with another machine where we noticed that the (working machine) had more 'sed' commands available than the (broken).

I deleted that old bin directory so the PATH continued until another bin directory was discovered, in a volume that was in use.

Comment: Try with git 2.8.3: unzip https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.8.3.windows.1/PortableGit-2.8.3-64-bit.7z.exe anywhere you want.

Comment: No joy, its the same error. I've tried a few different versions of git, uninstalling and reinstalling to no avail.

Comment: Running the same commands from a git (cmd) work fine. using SourceTree (GUI) works too for various different versions but running from bash seems to be the issue...

Comment: No need to install/uninstall: simple unzip of https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.8.3.windows.1/PortableGit-2.8.3-64-bit.7z.exe in for instance, `C:\git-2.8.3`, and then try: `set PATH=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\git-2.8.3\bin;C:\git-2.8.3\usr\bin;C:\git-2.8.3\latest` And try again your git commands with that *simplified* PATH.

Comment: same error `/git-2.8.3/mingw64/libexec/git-core/git-sh-setup: 30: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")`

Comment: Maybe you have a $HOME/.bashrc with something tricky in it?

Comment: I cant find a .bashrc file on my system at all. and all my other .gitconfig files remain unchanged as far as i can tell